# git lab - Cannot Create: This merge request already exists: ["Master"]

Tags: git, gitlab

I have force pushed with this command :

```
git push -f origin master
```

and it pushed fine
but when I went to git lab for submit, my commit message was for 5 days ago (my last commit) and I've
got this error:

**Cannot Create: This merge request already exists: ["Master]"**

I also need to mention that my new changes are in compare page and I can see and edit them but my commit message is for 5 days ago and when I hit submit button the above error shows up

any help?
[image: my new changes]
[image: error]

Answer (score 5):

You have to close all previous open merge requests first. You can check already existing open merge requests in the github/gitlab repository where you are doing merge request

Answer (score 2):

I use gitlab to merge，then get the error.Validate branches Cannot Create: This merge request already exists:

I just  checkout the project again, and pull push the two branch to gitlab, Then solve it.

Comment: thanks for your explaination but I solve this by closing request and push with no changes

Answer (score 1):

I had to switch to a different branch and push again to solve the issue